# Advanced Regex for splitting strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write an advanced regrex that will split my string in correct places.

Do you remember the [old phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text)) (T9), where you could simply do 22022 to write 'bb'
I need something similiar.

I got the splitting at the whitespaces(which implement the pause), but the rest is really hard.

For whitespace it is

```
var l = Regex.Split(a, @"\s");
```

but i would need following:`44204420442 should be 44, 2, 0, 44, 2, 0, 44, 2`
so it would split also after the character is changed compared to the previous one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of complex *regular expression* you can implement a simple loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> MySplit(String value) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

  char prior = '\0';

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (char current in value) {
    if (sb.Length != 0 && prior != current) {
      yield return sb.ToString();

      sb.Clear();
    }

    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(current))
      sb.Append(current);

    prior = current;
  }

  if (sb.Length > 0)
    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

Test:

```
string value = "44204420442";
string[] parts = MySplit(value).ToArray(); // if you want an array

// 44, 2, 0, 44, 2, 0, 44, 2
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", parts));

string value2 = "44 44 42";

// 44, 44, 4, 2
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", MySplit(value2)));
```

Comment: Hey!
Would your code work against
442 442 with the whitespace? How would I change it to work for that

Comment: @Egert Aia: if you want to split on *white spaces* as well, you have to add one `if` (see my edit)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting, it's easier to collect all the matches:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\d)\1*");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

You need to look at each `Match` object's `.Groups[0].Value` to get the entire match.